# Why has SpaceX changed Starship from carbon fiber composite to stainless steel?

Tags: spacex, materials, upper-stage, spacex-starship, composite-materials

Recently, there was news that SpaceX changed the material used for the BFS/Starship (upper stage of the BFR) from initially planned carbon fiber to metal which seems quite counter-intuitive as carbon fiber has a few desirable physical properties and, more importantly, low weight.

[image]

([source](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1077106553189093376))

What were the main reasons for choosing stainless steel over carbon fiber composite?

Comment: I'm sure they'll tell us at some point, until then this question will only invite speculation.

Comment: Musk has hinted at a presentation in March or April 2019.

Comment: will it be like the last one where he described the Dunning-Kruger effect as if it were something he'd come up with himself @Hobbes

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to tweets from Elon, at least part of the decision is due to their design for dealing with the reentry heat: instead of adding [ablators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_entry#Ablative) to cool the craft on reentry, Starship is going to actively cool the hot side with liquid methane. Steel is better at coping with this than carbon fiber.

[Tweet 1](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1077111607564464129):

> Usable strength/weight of full hard stainless at cryo is slightly better than carbon fiber, room temp is worse, high temp is vastly better

[Tweet 2](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1077353613997920257):

> Leeward side needs nothing, windward side will be activity cooled with residual (cryo) liquid methane, so will appear liquid silver even on hot side

(Also: [Skin will get too hot for paint. Stainless mirror finish. Maximum relfectivity.](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/1077353613997920257) [sic])

Comment: "so will appear liquid silver even on hot side" If this should be the melting point of silver at about 960 °C, that is light cherry red color of hot steel, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_heat). Steel looses a lot of its strength at this temperature and may be bend or cut by a blacksmith easily.

Comment: @Uwe: I interpret it that he means the steel will still look silver/grey during reentry and not glow red. But we'll know for sure once SpaceX is releasing all the details (Elon mentioned that's scheduled to happen in March or April).

Comment: If Elon Musk means the steel will still look silver/grey during reentry, why he used the word liquid? Or is "liquid silver" meant as the metal mercury or quicksilver?

Comment: @Uwe: Your guess is as good as mine here. We'd have to ask him. :-)

Comment: May be I am wrong, but some sentences by Elon Musk seems to be inprecise. Remember the space suit "tested to double vacuum pressure"?

Comment: He's really fixated on how shiny it is.

Comment: @Uwe Well if someone is on the cutting edge, minor details become unimportant. The minor detail here was that he has thought on the double of the pressure what the spacesuit should hold if it is in vacuum (which is probably $\approx 0.4$ atm), and not on the absolute pressure in vacuum ($\approx 0$ atm).

Comment: I believe sweating is no longer the approach, so this answer needs updating.

Answer (score 2):

Musk has said that the strength-to-weight ratio of the two materials is actually not all that different, but stainless is far less expensive and easier to work with. He has mentioned high scrap rates inherent in working with carbon fiber as a major contributor to its high cost. SpaceX is employing a rapid, iterative build/test cycle to achieve its end goals, requiring them to build a lot of vehicles, so unit cost and time-to-build become important considerations.